# SSIS package executes fine in BIDS but fails when ran as a job

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, bids

I have a package that extracts employee data from PeopleSoft and uploads it to a SFTP folder based on any change in the employee table on PeopleSoft. This package runs fine when executed from within BIDS but fails when executed as a job in SSMS. I have searched around with the error code and tried the following:

- Permission on the folder is fine
- Job is running in 32bit

> Message
>   Executed as user: domain\user. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.4033.0 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  8:35:38 PM  Error: 2015-01-03 20:35:51.84     Code: 0xC0029151     Source: Upload to Everbridge SFTP Execute Process Task     Description: In Executing "C:\Everbridge\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" "/script=FTPScript_Delete.txt" at "C:\Everbridge\", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  8:35:38 PM  Finished: 8:35:52 PM  Elapsed:  13.54 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Check Sql Server Agent account permissions

Answer (score 0):

Add working directory path  on Execute process Task

Answer (score 0):

this is all because of permissions assigned to it. go to services  find sql server job agent. go to logon tab and change the account to local system account(windows credentials) then it will consider local system account  and restart the services  the job  will execute without error. i hope this will help you